# How to edit the Boot Graphics Resource Table / Edit windows 8 BOOT LOGO?

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi, efi, bitmaps

I want to edit the screen which is displayed when windows 8 (starts) loads (/loading).

As for now it has the Toshiba logo, I want my custom logo or the windows default logo.

I have found that UEFI has something called "Boot Graphics Resource Table" and that it overides the default logo if there is a image present ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj963199(v=winembedded.81).aspx))

How can I edit the logo stored in UEFI firmware or Boot Graphics Resource Table?

if it's in the "bootres.dll", which does UEFI use? My disk (spread across a few system/usefi/windows/etc partitions) has around twenty bootres.dlls.

The bootres.dll is signed by Microsoft, but I don't have to worry because I can sign the file I edit myself with my own certificate.